# Parse verification email with image

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am currently using [Parse](https://parse.com) email verification to validate the user. `Parse` has given the option to send custom email for verification.  My question is:

Is it possible to include an image in that email? I would like to show an image at the end of the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please use parse-mailgun-adapter for **custom email templates** [From Here](https://github.com/sebsylvester/parse-server-mailgun)
2. Place your html files for custom templates in your root directory
3. you can use  tag to place your images but don't forget to give it an absolute url with for example

   < img src="https://www.aWebSite.com/anImageResource.png" />